# Thymeleaf how to handle non-existent session attribute

Tags: thymeleaf

I dont have to mess with Thymeleaf too often ...

I have an thymeleaf html template with a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo" th:value="${#session.getAttribute('foo')}" />
```

Works fine if I really do have a session attribute named foo. But sometimes depending on user selected option I don't have a foo attribute in my session. Get the following error:

```
Exception processing template "somePage": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#session.getAttribute('foo')" (template: "somePage" - line 29, col 6)>
```

I know I should have something like if exist else but I cannot get the syntax right:

```
th:value="${#session.getAttribute('foo')} ?: 'tai-bo'" />
```

Can someone point out my error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (works for me)

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" th:value="${#session.getAttribute('foo') != null ? 'foo is not null' : 'foo is null'}" />
```

Note also that support for the session object in expressions is removed starting with Thymeleaf 3.1.